# Send Enter Key to dialog prompt with Python

Tags: python

Good Evening All,

I have spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out. I tried everything but it seems not to work. I am launching a script via a windows batch file through python and a dialog box pops up with the "yes" already highlighted. All I want to do is press enter. I have seen subprocess and all but nothing happened.

```
import openpyxl
import os
import subprocess
import win32com.client
import time

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
print "Section Clear"

launch = os.system('C:/Users/luis.durani/Desktop/login.bat')
print "Section Clear"
```

Comment: Have a look at [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html).  I know it is not a complete answer but at least a point to start from.

Comment: Thanks Shintlor. I am looking for something else potentially, if possible.